# No Activity found to handle Intent - Got this error while trying to export csv file, is there any solution?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent, android-room, export-to-csv

I'm trying to export csv file from the room database, I implemented the whole code. The app crashed with error:

```
 android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=content://com.projects.android.udhaarkhata.fileprovider/transactions_csv_files/UdhaarKhataDatabase.csv typ=text/comma-separated-values flg=0x3 }
```

My Fragment class code is:

```
package com.projects.android.udhaarkhata.fragment


import android.graphics.Movie
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.Toast
import com.github.doyaaaaaken.kotlincsv.dsl.csvWriter
import com.projects.android.udhaarkhata.Database.Customer
import com.projects.android.udhaarkhata.Database.CustomerDatabase
import com.projects.android.udhaarkhata.Database.Transaction

import com.projects.android.udhaarkhata.R
import com.projects.android.udhaarkhata.generateFile
import com.projects.android.udhaarkhata.goToFileIntent
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_export_csv.*
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import kotlinx.coroutines.withContext
import java.io.File

/**
 * A simple [Fragment] subclass.
 */
class ExportCSVFragment : BaseFragment() {

    private lateinit var customerList: List<Customer>
    private lateinit var transactionList: List<Transaction>

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_export_csv, container, false)
    }

    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
        btnExportCSV.setOnClickListener {
            exportDatabaseToCSVFile()
        }


        launch {
            context?.let {
                customerList = getAllCustomers()
                transactionList = getAllTransactionsForAllCustomers()
            }
        }

    }

    private fun getCSVFileName() : String = "UdhaarKhataDatabase.csv"

    private fun exportDatabaseToCSVFile() {
        val csvFile = generateFile(requireContext(), getCSVFileName())
        if (csvFile != null) {
//            if (MOVIES_SHOWN) {
//                (shownFragment as MoviesListFragment).exportMoviesWithDirectorsToCSVFile(csvFile)
//            } else {
//                (shownFragment as DirectorsListFragment).exportDirectorsToCSVFile(csvFile)
//            }

            exportMoviesWithDirectorsToCSVFile(csvFile)

            Toast.makeText(context, "CSV file generated", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            val intent = goToFileIntent(requireContext(), csvFile)
            startActivity(intent)
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Unable to generate the CSV file", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    }

    // This is a suspend function which will get all the customers from database
    private suspend fun getAllCustomers(): List<Customer> {
        return withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            val customers = CustomerDatabase.getInstance(activity!!).getCustomerDao.getCustomers()
            customers
        }
    }

    private suspend fun getAllTransactionsForAllCustomers() : List<Transaction> {
        return withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            val transactions = CustomerDatabase.getInstance(activity!!).getTransactionDao.getAllTransactionsForAllCustomers()
            transactions
        }
    }

    fun exportMoviesWithDirectorsToCSVFile(csvFile: File) {
        csvWriter().open(csvFile, append = false) {
            // Header
//            writeRow(listOf("[id]", "[Customer]", "[Transaction]"))



            for (customer in customerList) {
                val customerName = customer.name
                val customerPhone = customer.phoneNumber
                val customerId = customer.id

                for (transaction in transactionList) {
                    if (customerId == transaction.id) {
                        val transactionAmount = transaction.amount
                        val youGave = transaction.youGave
                        val transactionCustomerId = transaction.id

                        writeRow(listOf(customerId, customerName, customerPhone, transactionCustomerId, transactionAmount, youGave))
                    }
                }
            }



//            moviesList.forEachIndexed { index, movie ->
//                val directorName: String = moviesViewModel.directorsList.value?.find { it.id == movie.directorId }?.fullName ?: ""
//                writeRow(listOf(index, movie.title, directorName))
//            }
        }
    }


}
```

The FileUtils.kt class contains the following code:

```
package com.projects.android.udhaarkhata

import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import androidx.core.content.FileProvider
import java.io.File

fun generateFile(context: Context, fileName: String): File? {
    val csvFile = File(context.filesDir, fileName)
    csvFile.createNewFile()

    return if (csvFile.exists()) {
        csvFile
    } else {
        null
    }
}

fun goToFileIntent(context: Context, file: File): Intent {
    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
    val contentUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, "${context.packageName}.fileprovider", file)
    val mimeType = context.contentResolver.getType(contentUri)
    intent.setDataAndType(contentUri, mimeType)
    intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION or Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION

    return intent
}
```

I've also updated the android manifest file :

```
<application>
   .
   .
   .
   <provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.projects.android.udhaarkhata.fileprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
    </provider>
</application>
```

I've also added file_paths.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <files-path name="transactions_csv_files" path="."/>
</paths>
```

How do I resolve this issue?
Please help me

Comment: There is no requirement for a user to have an app with an activity that can handle a MIME type of `text/comma-separated-values`. So, wrap your `startActivity()` call with `try`/`catch`, and if you get an `ActivityNotFoundException`, do something (e.g., error dialog saying that you cannot find a suitable app, or try a different `Intent`).

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks it worked, however the file generated is blank, seems like writeRow function in not working, any ideas?

Comment: I do not know how you are looking at the file. It is in `getFilesDir()`, so it is only accessible to your app and those that you enable via `FileProvider` and `startActivity()`. You might want to use Android Studio's Device File Explorer to see if the actual file is empty. If it is, confirm that you have data and are iterating over it to write the CSV. If you are, perhaps there is an issue in how you are using this Kotlin CSV library.

Comment: @CommonsWare if I manually add data like  -           writeRow(listOf("id", "Customer Name", "Customer Name","Transaction Amount", "You Gave")) , then it is working and adds the data into csv file, but, if I iterate data from the database then it is not adding into the csv file, may you please take a look at the above exportMoviesWithDirectorsToCSVFile method where I'm iterating the data from the database. I'm actually new to android and programming.